# Find all files in directory with extension .txt and .py with python using filter and map

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, tuples

How do I find files in a directory that end with `.txt` or `.py` in Python, using the filter and map function?

Comment: If you got the answer please select any answer as selected to complete the flow.

Answer (score 5):

`os.listdir` will get you a listing of the files.  Then you just need to write a function which returns `True` when the filename endswith `.py` or `.txt`:

```
filter(lambda x: x.endswith(('.txt','.py')), os.listdir(os.curdir))
```

... I really don't know how to incorporate `map` into it ...

Comment: The two *endswith()* calls can be combined into ``x.endswith((".txt", ".py"))``.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- Nice.  I did not know that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try list comprehensions like

```
[x for x in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] in ('.txt', '.py')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways:

A pure functional approach:

```
from operator import methodcaller
filter(methodcaller('endswith', ('.txt', '.py')), os.listdir('.'))
```

A list comprehension approach:

```
[fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.endswith(('.txt', '.py'))]
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob module to get those files

```
>>> import glob    
>>> glob.glob('*.py')
['test.py', 'a.py', 'b.py']
```